# How can I show the full process name in iotop?

Tags: ubuntu, process, top

I am using iotop to see which processes are reading from the disk. The process name column is small and some of the names are truncated:

```
gvfsd-tra~ec_spaw/1
gnome-sof~n-service
gnome-key~1,secrets
gnome-ter~al-server
gnome-key~s [gdbus]
```

Is there a way I can see the full names or command lines?

iotop 0.6 in Ubuntu 16.

Comment: See also `iotop -bo` for a batch mode showing only active processes where the argument list is not truncated.

Comment: Note that the name of  a process on Linux cannot be more than 15 bytes. What you're seeing is the argument list passed to the command the process is currently running.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a windowing system, simply make the terminal wider, usually by dragging an edge or corner. The 'COMMAND' column simply expands to fill the available space.

If you are doing this on a console, there is probably a utility to make the console a 'window' on a larger virtual screen to achieve the same end. stty might do it, or looking round the options in screen or tmux.

Comment: In `screen`: `^A:width -w 120` for instance, though left and right scrolling is a bit awkward and would have to be done in copy mode.